# Frightening Stokes Theorem Computation

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, vector-fields, stokes-theorem

I came across a rather frightening problem in my problem set and I am confused about it.

I need to compute the flux of a field $\vec F = \langle y, x^2, z(x^2-y^3)^7 \cos(e^{xyz}) \rangle$ through the upward-pointing surface $z= \sqrt {1 - \frac {x^2} 9 - \frac {y^2} 4} $.

I'm told it would be wise to use Stokes's Theorem and I'm also told to figure out the boundary to get a head start. I attempted to compute this integral with brute force, but it seems to be unintegrable that way.

How should I approach this problem?

Comment: The boundary is not difficult to find, it's an ellipse of semi axis, 3 and 2. But the field is not the curl of anything. By other side, I don't see the problem easier using the divergence theorem.

Comment: Are you sure it is not the flux of $curl \vec {F} = (y,x^2,f(x,y,z))$ that you want to compute?